# Shadow is not showing for UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, custom-cell, uistackview

I am trying to give shadow to a UIStackView. My stackview is in a prototypecell having some labels and buttons.
Firstly, I have made a reference of stackview with name **UIViewBank** in a class that is binded to my custom cell:

```
class CustChatBankCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var UIViewBank: UIStackView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And in my Controller I am using the extension in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell:CustChatBankCell = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomBankCell") as! CustChatBankCell
                    cell.UIViewBank.dropShadow()
                    return cell
                }
}
```

Extension code:

```
extension UIStackView {

    func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 501)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1

        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }
}
```

But shadow is not appearing.

Comment: check the clipToBounds property of your UIStackView

Comment: Have you tried not to set so huge shadowOffset? Try to set CGSize(width: 1, height: 1) for test.

Comment: @ReinierMelian, clipToBounds is checked

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov,I have tried your suggestion,but it did'nt worked for me.

Comment: Make another background view with clear background and add the shadow to it.

Comment: @ShareKnowledge check the answer provided by Sahil it seems that is the correct answer

Answer (score 26):

You can't do this because `UIStackView` is a non-drawing view, meaning that `drawRect()` is never called and its background color is ignored. Consider placing the `UIStackView` inside another `UIView` and giving that view a background color.

From Apple Docs

> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of
>   UIView
>   ; that is, it does not provide any user interface of its own. Instead, it just manages the position and size of its arranged views. As a result, some properties (like
>   backgroundColor
>   ) have no effect on the stack view. Similarly, you cannot override
>   layerClass
>   ,
>   draw(*:)
>   , or draw(*:in:).

Comment: What Sahil said above is entirely true, however there are some tricks around this. Try this approach: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stack-view-background-color/